# Play scala insert dynamic list of values from form to controller for value insertion

Tags: scala, playframework, form-submit, playframework-2.3, anorm

I am newbie to `scala`- `play frame work`.In my `view` page I have `plus button`.If I click the `plus` button every time It will generate a new row with two `text boxes` with  `delete` icon.If I click the `delete` button the current row will be deleted.For example If I entered the values in three rows I need to get the `List` of `String` values into my `Action` for entering into `Data Base`.[image]

I need `List<String>` values from both `contact person` and `contact no` into my `Controller Action` class for entering values in `DB`. I had completed the UI part using `javascript` need to work on the form `submit`.

**Edit**

I have done creating a new `three` fields with input type `id` of `contactperson[0],contactperson[1],contactperson[2] and contactno[0],contactno[1],contactno[2]`.If I submit I need to get the `contactperson`,`contactno` `array` values in my controller class.The rows are not pre defined it will generate as many as when click the plus button.

**Edit 2**

```
project table

|---------------------------
| projectid |  projectname  |
|------------------------   |
| 3         |  test project |
--------------------------

contact table

|--------------------------------------------------
| conid |  projectid |contactperson  | contatcno  |
|--------------------------------------------------
| 1     |  3         |jamal          |        123 |
---------------------------------------------------
|--------------------------------------------------
| 2     |  3         |karthi          |      1245 |
---------------------------------------------------
|--------------------------------------------------
| 3     |  3         |gopi         |          124 |
---------------------------------------------------
```

If this is my sample records means how can I use `simple`

```
case class projectEdit (  
  contactperson:List[Options[String]],
  contatcno:List[Options[String]],

)


    val simple = {

    get[List[Option[String]]]("contact.contactperson") ~
    get[List[Option[String]]]("contact.contatcno")  map {            
      case contactperson~contatcno
        => projectEdit(contactperson,contatcno)
    }
  }
```

I am using https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaForms#Repeated-values how could I map my `case` class `projectEdit`  with `scala anorm` like what we usually map the `String`,`Int`.I don't know how to map the `List[Options[String]]` with `sql anorm`

Comment: What is your question, Jamal?

Comment: @Kris I have edited the question.If you have any doubt please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set the `hard-coded` values in my `simple` variable.So it doesn't make any error on `compile/run` time. Let consider I have another variable `contactname` in `projectEdit`

```
case class projectEdit (  
  contactperson:List[Options[String]],
  contatcno:List[Options[String]],
contactname:String
)


    val simple = { 
   get[String]("contact.contactname")  map {            
      case contactname
        => projectEdit(List(Some("jamal")),List(Some("syed")),contactname)
    }
  }
```

In my `Action` class I get the values once the form `submit` is successful

```
profileedit =>{
 println("contact person list:"+profileedit.contactperson.flatten)
          println("contact no list:"+profileedit.contatcno.flatten)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should expose your controller Action as a JSRoute and then use javascript to grab those values and POST it to the JS endpoint. See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaGuide6 for more details (assuming you're using Java)